# Dnsmasq , redirect all but google.com

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, routing, router, dnsmasq

My router uses dnsmasq.
In my dnsmasq.conf, I write:
`address=/#/127.0.0.1`
in order to resolv any domain to my local server.
It works.

Now I'd like to make possible to join www.google.com. Any other domain is "redirected" to my local.

is this correct ?

```
address=/#/127.0.0.1
address=/google.com/#
```

Or should I do elsehow, or should I provide the google.com IP ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You're close.  Your second line should be `server=` instead.

```
address=/#/127.0.0.1
server=/google.com/#
```

Whereas `address` means "Resolve this domain and its subdomains as this address", `server` means "Ask this nameserver to resolve this domain and its subdomains."  The `server` directive supports `#` in the second position to mean "the default upstream server".

For more info, see the [`dnsmasq` man page](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html).  Search for `--server` or `--address`.